# how to separate two variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, random

I have this codes,and my problem is that the image and the text appears in one div. How can I separate the text and display it to another div while the image appears also on another div. but still when i reload the page, image 1 will correspond to text 1.same with image 2 it should also appear with text 2.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Random Text Plus Image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="quote"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var quotes = [
        {
          text: "text1",
          img:  "image1.jpg"
        },
        {
          text: "text2",
          img:  "image2.jpg",
        }
      ];
      var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
      document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML =
        '<p>' + quote.text + '</p>' +
        '<img src="' + quote.img + '">';
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

and updated code from comments:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <meta charset=utf-8 /> 
        <title>Random Text Plus Image</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="img"></div>
        <div id="text"></div>
        <script> 
            (function() { 
                var img = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]; 
                var text= ['text1','text2']; 
                var img = img[Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length)]; 
                var text = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];                 
                document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '<div>'+ text + '</div>'+ '<img src="' + img + '">'; })(); 
       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So put the one line in one div and set the image in another. Look at what the code is doing and do the same thing for another div.

Comment: i've already tried it,but it seems that i've done it wrong.that's my problem. i am a newbie on javascript. @epascarello

Comment: @epascarello <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Random Text Plus Image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="img"></div>
   <div id="text"></div>
  <script>
    (function() {
      var img = ["image1.jpg",  "image2.jpg"];
   var text= ['text1','text2'];
   
      var img = img[Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length)];
   var text = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];
      document.getElementById("img").innerHTML =
        '<div>'+ text + '</div>'+
        '<img src="' + img + '">';
    })();
  </script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: when i've manipulated the codes,  image1 doesn't pair up with text 1....sometimes it pairs it displays with text 2

Comment: Because you are using two random numbers!

Comment: @epascarello that's why I'm asking for a help, 'coz as i've said i'm new to javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = 
'<div><p>' + quote.text + '</p></div>' +
'<dic><img src="' + quote.img + '"></div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would change it from the first data structure that made more sense, but the issue you have is you are generating two different numbers!

```
var img = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]; 
var text= ['text1','text2']; 
var img = img[Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length)]; //random number 1
var text = text[Math.floor(Math.random() * text.length)];   //random number 2               
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '<div>'+ text + '</div>'+ '<img src="' + img + '">';
```

It should be something like

```
var img = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]; 
var text= ['text1','text2']; 
var ranNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * img.length);
var img = img[ranNum]; 
var text = text[ranNum];   
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = '<div>'+ text + '</div>';
document.getElementById("img").innerHTML = '<img src="' + img + '">';
```